# Duplicate symbol '_hasListeners' react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, apple-watch

I'm currently working on a project that requires both BLE and iWatch integration but for some reason when I install libraries to do both, I get this error

```
duplicate symbol '_hasListeners' in:

 /Users/wilcox/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-id/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNAppleHealthKit/libRNAppleHealthKit.a(RCTAppleHealthKit.o)
    /Users/wilcox/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-id/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-ble-manager/libreact-native-ble-manager.a(BleManager.o)
```

I'm using the libraries https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager and https://github.com/agencyenterprise/react-native-health

I've tried updating these libraries to the newest versions, cleaning the build folder and deleting derived data without any success. Is there anything I can do except hope the devs fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Find `Pods - Development Pods - RNAppleHealthKit - RCTAppleHealthKit.m`

And change:

```
bool hasListeners;
```

to:

```
static bool hasListeners;
```

And then build the project, will fix it.